# Database schema for one to many relationship

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I want to create the database schema for following query

1)it will have one entity(column) category which will have multiple subcategories

2) and that subcategory can have multiple url associated with it

how many tables will i need to create and how the relationship between tables would be ?

Comment: Please read [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what you are able to do with justification & ask a specific question where stuck. This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 tables:

1. category (id, name)
2. subcategory (id, name, category_id)
3. url (id, url, subcategory_id)